# Confusion regarding net acceleration of the bob in the bottommost point of the trajectory of a pendulum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation, acceleration, centripetal-force

Here is my analysis from the inertial frame on it:

At the bottom most point,

- $g$ acting downwards
- $v^2/r$ (centripetal acceleration) acting upwards

So the net acceleration, a = $(v^2/r)-g$ right?

What makes me ask this is because recently I was doing an analysis on the oscillatory motion of a pendulum and I was trying to derive an equation for: *the angular amplitude of the pendulum for which the acceleration of the ball are equal in its extreme and bottom most position*

So I wanted to know the proof of this statement "*centripetal acceleration is the **Net** acceleration along radial direction*" which I found from my research and which I believe is the reason for me being wrong.

My attempt to write the proof: $T-mg=mv^2/r$ is the net centripetal force acting at the bottom-most point and the value of T. But what is the value of T?

I totally confused at this point. Any help to clear my misunderstandings and basics would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a mass going around a circle of radius $r$ at constant speed $v$. Since we know how it moves, we can calculate the acceleration of this mass (the rate of change of velocity), irrespective of whatever forces may be acting upon it. This acceleration is called centripetal acceleration, and happens to point toward the center of the circle, with magnitude $v^2/r$. Again, we know this just from the kinematics of the mass. When things are not moving in a straight line, they instantaneously trace a circle, and centripetal acceleration by definition is the component of the acceleration pointing toward the center of this circle.

Now let's go back to the pendulum. When the bob is at its lowest position, it is instantaneously undergoing just such a circular motion, with radius $r$ and speed $v$. Consequently, it has an upward acceleration of $v^2/r$. This is where the forces enter the picture: from Newton's second law,
$$T - mg = m \frac{v^2}{r}.$$

You can then calculate $T$ as $mg+mv^2/r$.